# MYSQL join and group by

Tags: mysql

I am having trouble getting the syntax right with a table join in MYSQL. I have two tables as below...

```
primary_table

agent_id | primary_area | key
-----------------------------
   10    |xx1           | 1  
   11    |xx2           | 2  
   12    |xx3           | 3  
etc...


secondary_table

agent_id | sec_area     | key
-----------------------------
   34    |xx1           | 5  
   37    |xx1           | 6  
   38    |xx7           | 8  
etc...
```

All I am trying to do is search (for example) both tables for the `agent_id` that has xx1 as a value in both the `primary_area` and 'sec_area'. I need to use `LIKE` as this is a search function and it is possible that a user would want to search for all that have the vale `xx`.

The returned data then needs to be grouped by `agent_id` and kept in an array.

Comment: what is your desired result?

Comment: Something in the direction of `SELECT * FROM primary_table WHERE agent_ID LIKE %$search UNION SELECT * FROM secondary_table WHERE agent_ID LIKE %$search`

Comment: desired result is to select the agent ids that match a search of say xx1 from both tables and then group them by the agent id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
SELECT agent_id FROM primary_table WHERE primary_area LIKE "%1"
UNION
SELECT agent_id FROM secondary_table WHERE sec_area LIKE "%1"
```

---

`Comment: how would I group the results by agent_id using UNION`

```
SELECT
  p.id
FROM
  primary_table AS p
JOIN
  sec_table AS s
ON
  p.id=s.id 
WHERE
  p.area LIKE "%1" AND s.area LIKE "%1"
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/70f29/8)**

Comment: thanks - how would I group the results by agent_id using UNION.

Comment: I updated my answer taken this into consideration, @Sideshow. You can also check the SQL Fiddle.